# Get the highest number of concurrently logged on users using powershell (Windows Server 2008)

Tags: windows, powershell, authentication, max

I wanted to generate a report that show the highest number of concurrently logged on users of a machine per day (for a specific date range). Could this be done using PowerShell script? This should include remote log in as well (e.g. using RDP).

This needs to be done on our client's machine and we're not allowed to install any software on their servers.

If this can't be achieved using PowerShell, any other methods using any built-in functions of Window Server 2008 should be ok.

Comment: I'm sure that you could do this with PowerShell using system logs to track when a user logs on and off the system or probably several other ways, but StackOverflow is not a code writing service. When you have some code that you have written and have gotten an error, we can help with the errors, but we are not here to do it for you.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I'll try writing the code myself, if I have any trouble, I'll post it here. Regards

Comment: You might be able to count the logon/logoff events in the Securiy event log..